# They all gave the same one word answer - What answer did they give?

Tags: word, situation

Here's a slightly different, fairly easy one.

> Three men travel for almost a day across an unknown distance to a meeting point.  One travelled by car, another by horse and the other by boat.  When they arrived they were all asked how they had been able to reach the meeting place. They all gave different answers, but only one word was heard.

**What word(s) did they speak?**

Comment: Hmmm perhaps the ending should be "They all gave different answers, but only one word was heard." This eliminates some of the ambiguity, I mean they quite simply could have said "Travel" or something similar.

Comment: I've put this puzzle on hold as too broad; I think, in this case, that the vagueness around the word "how" allows for too many answers, all of which would nominally be correct. Looking at the answers below, nearly all of them fit, with different interpretations of the word "how."

Comment: @Emrakul I've updated the question to try and remedy the problem but I completely agree that the question was far too broad.  Regretfully, as I'd admitted previously, I clearly hadn't put enough thought into this puzzle.  I apologise to the submitters of valid answers below who's answers may have been invalidated by my update(s). Greg - thanks for the suggestion.  I've snatched your wording.

Comment: @BrentHackers That's fair! I think this edit definitely helps with a decent part of the broadness, too. I'll leave it to voters in the VTRO queue, since I'm on the fence about whether it's still too broad, but yeah, this helps. And it's alright, it happens! A closed question here or there doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

They all said

> /rōd/
>  {rowed, road, rode}

Horseback:

> I rode a horse.

Car:

> My car travelled on the road.

Boat:

> I rowed the boat.

Comment: Yep.  You got it.  +1

Comment: @BrentHackers so you were looking for a *homophone*.

Comment: I.e. they didn't all give the same one-word answer.

Comment: @LarsH Yes they did.  Read it out loud.

Comment: @LeppyR64: Just because it sounds the same doesn't mean it's the same answer.

Comment: @LarsH What the OP says goes though

Comment: @Insane: I agree, what the OP says about the intended answer goes: That is the intended answer. What I was questioning is the correctness of the question.

Comment: @LarsH It sounded like you were questioning my answer.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry my comment was unclear.

Answer (score 90):

They all said

> "Mustang", giving the brand of the car and boat and the breed of horse

Note:
The question at the time of posting was (**emphasis** mine):

> Three men travel for almost a day across an unknown distance to a meeting point. One travelled by car, another by horse and the other by boat. When they arrived they were all asked how they had reached the meeting place **and, without lying, they all gave the same one word answer.**

Comment: Damn.  No.  But I love it.  Can' fault it.   I clearly should have spent more time on this one.  +1

Comment: This should be accepted as answer since it's one word as requested.

Comment: @nikamed The answer was given verbally.  My answer is three words, but they would all sound exactly the same.

Comment: This answer is superior since the words are homonyms instead of merely homophones.

Comment: @MarchHo While I like the answer, I disagree that it is better. It is actually exploiting a not too well defined question, but by using a *Name* you can fit *anything*. f.e. "They all said Hobo", because that's what they call a "means-of-transport". They all said "Boat", because that was the name of the horse and the nickname of the rather large car. etc. etc.

Comment: @BmyGuest Your argument isn't as strong as presented, since the strength of the answers stems from the fact that the names are not merely arbitrary, but are in fact both popular brands of cars and boats.

Comment: I agree with BmyGuest.   Particularly because while a Mustang is a univerally well known car, the same can't be said for the boat brand.

Comment: This one is better and more subtle ;D

Comment: This is not better-- read the the question. "Different answers but only one word was heard"

Comment: @ev3commander, I think the question was worded differently when this answer was written.

Answer (score 41):

They all said:

> alone

Valid if not 100% useful.

Comment: Not a homonym but clever.  I like it.  +1

Answer (score 15):

They all answered

> "Ferry"...

---

> The car drives onto the ferry, the horse rides over on it, and the man who went by boat simply walked onto it

Answer (score 15):

*Note*: Since the question didn't mention the homonym requirement and I only noticed the tag after reading other answers, the following are not homonyms.

I think there are lots of answers that could work here, but I'll go with this.

They all said:

> **Quickly**

Alternately:

> **Slowly**

Alternately:

> **Noneya**

Alternately:

> **Tired**

Comment: What is "Noneya"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [It's the oddest thing you will ever get in any answer](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=noneya) :/

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Noneya" is slang for "None of your business." http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=noneya

Comment: Never heard it before.

Answer (score 12):

Puns are allowed? They all said:

> 'mare, mare, meer-mer.

The car driver who went through a

> 'mare because the traffic jam was painful (short [slang for nightmare](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mare), related to a very unpleasant or frustrating experience),

the horse rider who rode

> [a female horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mare) (mare),

and the sailor, speaking a germanic (in some German regions, in Dutch) or french language in which a large body of water allowing a boat ("sea" or "lake") is sometimes called

> "[meer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Meer)" or "[mer](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mer)".

Comment: Well it certainly is a creative answer.

Comment: Though in Dutch, that actually means "lake" (it's a 'false friend' to the German word).

Comment: @CompuChip Well, "the other by boat", could be on a lake too. Recorrecting

Answer (score 11):

With your wording, the answer could be

> *traveling*.

After all, they all

> did travel to get there.

Comment: That was my first thought as well.

Comment: Agreed with your 1st option.

Answer (score 6):

Also not the intended answer, but they certainly arrived

> tired

because they

> travelled almost a day.

Answer (score 6):

Of course they all arrived...

> Safely.

Because after all...

> That is what they assumed the question was about - not how they got there, but how they were personally.

Answer (score 4):

Not the intended answer, but it could also be

> North, or any other arbitrary direction.

Comment: Sort of, but that doesn't answer the question how...

Answer (score 3):

Despite there being an accepted answer, I can't resist suggesting another word:

> "together".

It fails the intention of the homonym/homophone tag as well as the spirit of the question, but nothing in the question directly contradicts the possibility of

> the men travelling along a canal path to a town hall or pub or other "meeting point" -- a place where people meet in general.